# Is there an npm ls equivalent in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am bumping versions in a project and find `npm ls` really handy to find out what versions are used.

Is there an equivalent command in `rails/bundler`?

Answer (score 2):

```bash
bundle list
```

Use `bundle help` for a list of commands.

[Bundler command line reference.](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-list.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec gem dependency` is pretty useful also and gives me all I need.